# how to change the first item of a Spinner in Kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, fonts, android-spinner

I've created this spinner:

```
var typesSpinner=arrayOf("")
spinner.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        typesSpinner = arrayOf(getString(R.string.select_value),getString(R.string.menu),getString(R.string.dessert),getString(R.string.drinks),getString(R.string.custom_h),getString(R.string.custom_l))
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.spinner_row, typesSpinner)
        spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

What's the best way to change the first value?:

> getString(R.string.select_value)

I've tried creating a Spanned object so I can use htmlformat but then, I don't know how to create the spinner using it.
I also created a TextView tag with the formatted text:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/select_value"
            android:textFontWeight="1000"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

but this doesn't do anything.